# Why do we wear different colors on different days of Navratri?

Tags: puranas, festivals, durga, devi, navrathri

Each day of Navratri is associated with a different color as mentioned in [this article](http://www.india.com/festivals-events/navratri-colours-2017-with-dates-list-of-9-different-coloured-dresses-to-wear-during-navaratri-festival-to-please-goddess-durga-2453351/).

> **How are Navratri colours decided and why do they change every year?**
>
> The first colour of the Navratri is decided based on the week day when the festival begins or when Ghatsthapna or Pratipada falls. The remaining eight days then follow a fixed cycle of colors. Each day is dedicated to one particular form of Goddess Durga. Here’s a look at nine different colours to be worn on each day of Navratri 2017 festival according to Drik Panchang.

**Is there any scriptural basis to this selection?**

Comment: I also have this question! And the colors also are not exactly the same every year for some reason.

Comment: Yes this is different each time, have wondered the same thing.